# Ajuda com DateTangePicker no jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Estou utilizando o jQuery Date Range Picker em um formulario. Segue o código no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brro4jzp/1/)

Meu problema está em quando eu clino na input Entrada aparece o date range picker normalmente, mas quando clico na data de entrada precisava que ele fechasse e abrisse na input de Saida. Do modo que está eu seleciono a data de entrada e de saida pela input de entrada.

Alguem sabe como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Após selecionar a primeira data, colocar a div do datepicker abaixo do input da data final, serve como solução?

Comment: Repara que no código que passei no jsfiddle quando seleciono a entra o date range picker fica so na input de entrada. Repara como funciona no site da https://www.decolar.com/ era daquele jeito que eu precisava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não me aprofundei nos eventos que o próprio datepicker disponibiliza, talvez tenha alguma forma mais "correta" de fazer isso. Eu simplesmente detecto o clique no datepicker, se após o clique a data inicial for preenchida, reposiciona o datepicker abaixo do input da data final.

```
$(".date-picker-wrapper").click(function(){
    if($(this).find(".start-day").html().length > 4){
        $(this).css('left',$("#datasaida").offset().left);
  }
});
```

Segue um fiddle do código: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/brro4jzp/2/)

*Nota que ao redimensionar a página a posição inicial é restaurada, da para tratar isso com [resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Tem como abrir o DatePicker ao clicar no input de saida tambem?

Comment: Abrir no `dataentrada` ou no `datasaida` mesmo? (no datasaida é um pouco mais complicado :P)

Comment: Abrir no datasaida so para mudar a data de saida. tem como?

Comment: @Newtech acho que nesse caso, nós temos que fazer a mesma coisa que fizemos pro `dataentrada`, ao clicar no `datasaida` posicionar o datepicker no `dataentrada`, olhei na doc. não encontrei nada sobre começar selecionando o intervalo a partir da data final :/ deixa a pergunta em aberto ai, talvez alguém venha com uma outra alternativa p/ resolver essa questão.

Comment: não precisa começar selecionar apartir da data final. so dando para abrir o data picker pela datasaida ja está bom